# Adding vercel.json breaks Vercel deployments

Tags: svelte, vite, server-side-rendering, vercel, sveltekit

Adding a `vercel.json` file with the following cron job breaks Vercel deployments on `master` in my SvelteKit project.

```
{
  "crons": [
    {
      "path": "/api/cron",
      "schedule": "* * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

With no logs or anything to indicate what the issue is.

I have a cron job setup in `/src/routes/api/cron/+server.js`

```
import { invalidate } from "$app/navigation"

export function GET(req) {
  if (req.headers.get('Authorization') === `Bearer ${process.env.CRON_SECRET}`) {
    invalidate('calendar:load')

    return new Response("Success!")
  } else {
    return new Response('Not found', {
      status: 404
    })
  }
}
```

But it seems like there is a configuration issue that's causing a completely silent fail.

Any ideas? Or at least ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the hobby plan? If so, hobby accounts are limited to daily cron jobs.

e.g.: this cron expression (0 * * * *) would run every hour, more than once per day and it breaks the configuration but if you change to (0 6 * * *) that runs only at 06:00 am once per day it will be ok.